# How would you make a queenside pawn storm opening idea work?

Tags: opening, learning, strategy, pawn-structure, attack

I played a [Lichess bullet game](https://lichess.org/1YMDFmZO) as Black in which I disregarded any opening theory because I just wanted to mount up a pawn storm on the queenside. Has anybody come across this idea? It seems to me that a French Defense-like position with the e6 and d5 pawns blocked would make this to work. Also, the pair of bishops seems quite important here and I think that when established, this pawn structure would limit White's space and, if he castles, allows for pressure along both sides of the board. How would you make this work though?

```
[Title "abranzyck-LIR1618, Lichess, 8/24/19"]
[FEN "*"]

1. f4 e6 2. Nf3 d5 3. d3 a5 4. e4 c6 5. e5 Nh6 6. h3 b5 7. Be2 Bd7 8. O-O Na6 9. Be3 c5 10. Bf2 d4 11. Bh4 Be7 12. Ng5 Nf5 13. Qe1 Bc6 14. Bf3 Bxf3 15. Rxf3 Nxh4 16. Qxh4 h6 17. Qh5 g6 18. Qh4 Qd5 19. Nd2 O-O-O 20. Nde4 hxg5 21. Qf2 f5 22. Nxg5 Bxg5 23. fxg5 Rh5 24. g4 fxg4 25. Rf7 Rxg5 26. Kh2 Rh8 27. Rf1 Rxh3+ 28. Kg1 g3 29. Qf6 Qh1#
```

Comment: @RewanDemontay yeah, I don't know why I didn't

Comment: Nope,no problem, thanks for the edit by the way. I could have also played 26. g4 g3 to take his queen

Comment: @RewanDemontay thanks :) i hope to get better by being here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at some games with the English opening (after, for example 1.c4 e5 2.Nc3 Nc6 3.g3, where white rushes for a strong queenside attack based on Rb1, b4-b5.

The Sicilian Defence (Classical, Closed, Najdorf, Dragon, Taimanov or Scheveningen variations also provide good examples)

Some lines on the French Defence also have examples of queenside storm from Black, but I cannot recommend you anything in particular. Of course, even in the openings I mentioned, there will be plenty of examples where other plans are used instead. Be patient with your search until you find something useful for you

Answer (score 2):

That is a beautiful checkmate, but I personally don't consider a pawnstorm in the opening or early midgame a really good idea, since its easy to penetrate and it loses in terms of development.

But if you were to make a queenside pawnstorm, you could probably start with the queens gambit? You can probably push your queen pawns and still end up with a playable midgame in that case. As you mentioned, the bishops are important (and so are the knights) so you maybe would like to get your minors out and attacking or supporting the pawns.

Answer (score 2):

In your example the game was basically played on the kingside only as your "pawn storm" did not get beyond the 5th rank. With or without pawn storm white would not really want to put pieces on the queenside. White made some strange decisions starting with Bh4. Likely a better plan for white would have been to develop pieces quickly (e.g. a knight to e4) and open the position while black was still somehwat less developed.

Anyway, IMO, having a fixed plan like a "pawn storm" for every game in mind is a bad idea. You should investigate the position at hand and then decide what plan to follow based on that.

If you like positions with queenside pawn storms, see David's reply for openings where it often is a good idea.

Generally speaking pawn storms are often started in opposite side castling and if there is already a weakness (e.g. a pawn has moved out of line) in the opponent's position that you can attack with a pawn storm. You also want to have your development completed or almost completed before you open the position.